# How to add count() to a complicated mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I have a complicated MySQL query and I would like to add another element to the query but I just can't figure out how to do it.

I want to count the number of times `file` exists in a table called `like_unlike` WHERE `file = page_id` which I can then echo out later in the script. I hope it makes sense, many thanks.

I think I need to add this to my query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM like_unlike WHERE file=$page_id;
```

This is my query

```
    SELECT up.id, up.file, up.title, p.user_name, p.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(cp.user_id, '~', cp.user_name) SEPARATOR '|') AS tagGroup
FROM tbl_uploads up
LEFT JOIN tbl_users p ON up.user_id = p.user_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_collab c ON up.file = c.file AND c.approved = 'yes'
LEFT JOIN tbl_users cp ON cp.user_id = c.collab_userid
GROUP BY up.file ORDER BY up.id
```

Comment: Maybe try a subquery , something like `SELECT table.*, (SELECT COUNT(table2.id) FROM table2) AS 'numberOfId' FROM table ...` you can then get the data as the parameter `numberOfId`

Comment: Thanks, I'm working through this, apologies, I wrote the wrong query here (now updated but similiar).

Comment: And for what reason does everything have to be in the same query? What's exactly wrong with issuing a query that simply returns the count and then the one that returns the data? Please don't answer "performance" because that answer would be wrong.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The reason I'm doing everything in one query is that the results of the query are displayed on one page, a whole range of pictures where users are displayed who have 'associated' themselves to certain pictures. So what the query does is display all the pictures from the database and then checks to see if a user is associated with that picture. It also shows date of posting and now I want to add how many 'likes' each picture has. I assumed this all has to be done with one query.